# Visual Studio/C++: How to turn off certain first-chance exception debug messages?

Tags: visual-studio, exception, visual-c++, debugging, cgal

When I execute my C++ code (which uses the `CGAL` library) under debug mode, I see a lot of debug messages in the `Output` window about a first-chance exception `CGAL::Uncertain_conversion_exception`. I am aware of what a [first-chance exception](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105675) is.

Now, how do I turn off the display of debug messages for this *one* kind of exception (`CGAL::Uncertain_conversion_exception`)?

I like my debug messages as detailed as possible, but once I know what a certain exception is about and I have dealt with it, I would like it to go away. For example, in this case the CGAL exception is [supposedly naive](http://www.cgal.org/FAQ.html#uncertain_exception) (and informative) and not a cause for concern. I would like to turn it off, **but** still be able to keep my eyes open for any other (new) first-chance exceptions. Is this possible in Visual Studio 2008? Am I asking for too much?

Answer (score 10):

I don't think there is a way.

You can right-click into the output window and disable *all* exception messages, but it doesn't come with anymore of a filtering ability.

That said, if you're desperate, you can save the output, filter it, and, using a simple tool added to the Tools menu, dump it back into the output window (where it appears under your tool's title instead of "Debug"). I've done this before, but usually this is too much hassle for too little gains.

Comment: ... *You can right-click into the output window and disable all exception messages* ... Ha! What I looked for. Never underestimate the power of a well-placed right-mouse-click.

Answer (score -4):

I don't think that will be possible to do using VS2008. However, you can use the [DbgView.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) and set the filter to include/exclude the strings you want to display.

Comment: First-chance exceptions don't display anything in DbgView. The OP is asking how to make the Visual Studio debugger stop displaying them.